# Anyway to set a default only when there is parse error for @value

Tags: java, spring, config

In Spring, you could use `@Value("${num:123}") private int number;` to inject the value number.

Clearly the default will work when there is no num field in the configuration file.

However, when there is a malformatted one. Spring will throw the error like:

```
09:54:28.392 [main] WARN org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'valuesApp': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'number'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "string"
```

I know you could make the value injected type as String, then manually convert it to Integer type (can catch error etc.). However, is there any more elegant way of handling case like this? Such that Spring will use the default value in case of configuration file's one is malformatted.

Comment: I think one question to ask is why you would have a malformed value in the configuration file in the first place? The config file is supposed to be a source of truth in your application. If you really needed to handle this case, parsing a String might be the best solution.

Comment: I completely agree with you. However, it was not my code originally there. I just want to refactor it this way so to pass the code review.